# SQL Triggers and streaminsight - any StreamInsight Guru's out there?

Tags: sql-server, streaminsight, triggers

when data is entered into a table it fires a trigger which then copies it to a different table

I want to use stream insight when this trigger is firing and copying the amended data to a different table.

how can i get data into an input adapter from a trigger in table(event)
how can i use a trigger as an event for input adapter for getting data in streaminsight?

Comment: Are you wanting to do anything with this data that is being copied from table to table?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? What will StreamInsight provide you that the triggers don't? StreamInsight isn't an ETL tool - that's what you seem to want to use it for.